# Event-triggering in Spring

Tags: java, spring, event-handling, scheduled-tasks, task

I need to trigger an event-triggered task using Spring. The task should be triggered when a specific JMS message comes, as in this example :

```
@Override
protected void processMessage(MessageClass myMessage) {
    Event event = (Event) (myMessage.toString());
    if (event.getType() == Type.KEEPALIVE) {
        // trigger the task
    }
}
```

My plan is to use the TaskScheduler from Spring but it seems that events are not supported there.

Comment: What's the origin of the 'event'? Is it a tme expiration? Application condition or external? (e.g user, JMS, TCP/I

Comment: external JMS message.